# Reading end tag using XmlDocument class in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Is there a way I can read the endtag e.g.  using XMLDocument class. Due to some restrictions I cannot use XmlREader or XmlTextReader. In MSDN it is mentioned that I can use XmlNodeType.EndElement only with XMLReader [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). My code is something like this:

```
 XmlDocument doc = functionWhichReturnsXmlDoc();
 XmlNodeList nodes =textDoc.ChildNodes;
 foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
 switch (node.NodeType)
   {
     case XmlNodeType.Element:
     XmlNodeList nodes =textDoc.ChildNodes;
           switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    //do something
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    //do something
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                // THIS EVER EXECUTES   
            }
         }
}
```

My XML File"

```
<Text >
<environment>
    <Tempratue>
        <element id="COLD">Cold</element>
        <element id="MILd">Mild</element>
        <element id="HOT">Hot</element>
    </Tempratue>
        <element id = "Windy">true</element>
</environment>
<dish>
<element id = "dish1">1111</element>
<element id = "dish2">2222</element>
</dish>

</Text>
```

What I am trying to get the output as an list of string:-

```
/Text/Environment/Temprature/COLD
/Text/Environment/Temprature/MILD
/Text/Environment/Temprature/HOT
/Text/Environment/Windy
/Text/dish/dish1
/Text/dish/dish2
```

Thanks in advance.

--AAT

Comment: What information are you looking to retrieve from the closing tag?  It's not clear what your problem is here.

Comment: I am trying to create a string which includes the tag name and the id of <element> something like this: /Text/Temprature/COLD  or /Text/Temprature/HOT ..

Comment: And why do you need to detect closing tags in order to do that? Do you want to just produce a list of all of the `<element>`s paths, or is it more involved than that?

Comment: How would I solve the scenario when there are nested tags. Dont I have to know when the inner tag ends?

Comment: Attributes are a property of opening, not closing tags.  Are you trying to create an XPath expression for a given node or something?

Comment: I think people can give better answer if you post what you  expect from your sample xml.

Comment: Yes, something like that. However, I do not want to include <element> in the path, instead use its Id. Every <element> will have an ID attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you envisioned your algorithm working, but I'm pretty sure you're going about it the wrong way.  This is one way that you can provide the list of paths that you've described:

```
internal static List<string> BuildPaths(XmlDocument doc)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();

    BuildPaths(doc.DocumentElement, paths);

    return paths;
}

private static void BuildPaths(XmlNode node, List<string> paths, string prefix = "/")
{
    if (node.Name == "element")
    {
        // end case - elements named "element"
        paths.Add(prefix + node.Attributes["id"].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        // iterate through child nodes that are either not named element or that 
        // have an attribute named "id" (i.e. skip elements named "element" that 
        // lack an id attribute)
        foreach (XmlNode child in node.SelectNodes("*[not(self::element) or @id]"))
        {
            BuildPaths(child, paths, prefix + node.Name + "/");
        }
    }
}
```

When this is run on your sample XML, the result is a list of the following strings:

```
/Text/environment/Tempratue/COLD
/Text/environment/Tempratue/MILd
/Text/environment/Tempratue/HOT
/Text/environment/Windy
/Text/dish/dish1
/Text/dish/dish2
```

And here's an approach that I like a little better because it obeys functional programming principles. In this situation, the first `BuildPaths()` method above would be unneeded; you can pass the `XmlDocument` directly into this method:

```
private static List<string> BuildPaths(XmlNode node, string prefix = "/")
{
    // Get child node if current node is the root
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Document) { node = node.FirstChild; }

    if (node.Name == "element")
    {
        return new List<string> { prefix + node.Attributes["id"].Value };
    }
    else
    {
        return node.SelectNodes("*[not(self::element) or @id]")
                   .OfType<XmlNode>()
                   .Select(n => BuildPaths(n, prefix + node.Name + "/"))
                   .SelectMany(l => l)
                   .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to detect the EndElement nodes, simply work in reverse.
Store your pathing information in such a way that you know where you are, then you can print out the path in order from outside to inside.

I would do this with either a `List<string>` or a `StringBuilder`, List would be easier to manipulate.  Simply store the string you wish to print when you enter a new subnode group, and add node name or attribute value as desired, then write a printout function that interprets the list correctly.